# Admob not filling all the width

Tags: java, android, resize, size, admob

I have a problem with the admob banner size:
My test terminals are Samsung Galaxy s (480x800) and Asus eee pad transformer (800x1200).
In the [admob doc](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html) the banner sizes im using are 320x50 for phones and 728x90 for tablets.

With 480x800 (and portrait) the add is expanded and fill all the layout but in landscape or with the tablet the banner only take a portion and the rest is black.

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: How are you containing the ad in a webview/imageview etc?

Comment: I have the same problem....arggg

Comment: could you explain how you supply different ads on phone and tablet?

Answer (score 14):

You have to set the flag `SMART_BANNER` in the adView attribute `adSize`. like that:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="@string/devices_id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the apps are like yours it is not a problem , it is hard to get it to fill the space in landscape mode !! Don't Worry

Answer (score 0):

As per Google [Banner Ad Customization](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner) you can use Smart Banners

> Note: The smart banner view in your layout must consume the full width
>   of the device. If it doesn't, you'll get a warning with the message
>   "Not enough space to show ad", and the banner will not be displayed.

To use Smart Banners, specify the constant SMART_BANNER for the ad size:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
```

[image: Smart Banners]